# JavaScript library to manipulate EXIF/XMP data of in-memory jpegs

Tags: javascript, image, exif, xmp

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that allows you to add XMP metadata to JPEGs created with  `canvas.toDataURL()`. I assume they don't have any metadata included, so it's about rebuilding the JPEG binary data with proper EXIF blocks added - as XMP is on top of EXIF.

All I could find are EXIF readers, but no writers.

Do you know any such libraries, or best candidates for porting in other languages?

Comment: So how did you solve this?

Comment: I've made a custom encoder for my needs: https://github.com/panrafal/depthy/blob/master/app/scripts/classes/GDepthEncoder.js